# json open data in google maps

Tags: json, google-maps

this is a google example. Why I can't just change the https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json 
in 
http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v4/gis/lezafbakening.json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
  });

  // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script> // api key is ok
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json [doesn't work on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u9da04zo/), it returns an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

The comment in the code:

> // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.

indicates a potential issue.

However, with [your json](http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v4/gis/lezafbakening.json), [I get a different error](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u9da04zo/1/): `Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection`

Your JSON is not valid GeoJSON for the [DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), as indicated in the error, there is no top level Feature or FeatureCollection.  You can use http://geojsonlint.com/ to check your GeoJSON.

Your JSON:

```
{"paging":{"records":1,"pages":1,"pageCurrent":1,"pageNext":null,"pagePrev":null,"pageSize":1},"data":[{"id":"2","objectid":"1","geometry":"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[4.3752648501046,51.235671109447],[4.3768261156089,51.235987379867],[4.378205111297,51.236258380179],[4.3793189154647,51.236424751374],[4.381175249257,51.236619570007],[4.3821299391582,51.236714586479],[4.3826224317521,51.236738309085],[4.3847741845381,51.236652409815],[4.3870320006657,51.236566455329],[4.3905641334774,51.236418346457],[4.3933355001615,51.236027810783],[4.3953204030054,51.235751501796],[4.3964719325386,51.235580002999],[4.397631024507,51.235398977832],[4.3989492000278,51.235198875137],[4.4004535188848,51.235118174476],[4.4024418721928,51.235102784205],[4.4025175087519,51.235345894895],[4.4032165369956,51.235338394238],[4.403406877327,51.235341114003],[4.4044813217503,51.23533389126],[4.4047722441325,51.235316678533],[4.4050631360141,51.235259511945],[4.4053904063446,51.235219455944],[4.4057540767169,51.235219340598],[4.4060359480456,51.235253495989],[4.4064318055827,51.235325580515],[4.4067051745177,51.236067480356],[4.4067816576535,51.236932157158],[4.408069417218,51.236957496301],[4.4085517807897,51.236992303044],[4.4085551128357,51.237861034679],[4.408897111612,51.237856366303],[4.4092133965522,51.237852607418],[4.4092596122389,51.237690514702],[4.409307498352,51.237005585527],[4.4115683830778,51.23698955552],[4.4146387269243,51.236929323909],[4.4178627148587,51.236828131985],[4.4186098703507,51.236911526049],[4.4188646220169,51.237071229427],[4.4188672599631,51.239491250744],[4.4190314627796,51.239982033231],[4.4194137832192,51.240369984415],[4.4197606223084,51.241327202393],[4.4197599521063,51.244000523224],[4.4205172754282,51.244181323957],[4.4206091889183,51.241231702419],[4.4208346952824,51.240248765404],[4.4239856975874,51.239296052026],[4.4291989404206,51.237378040829],[4.4309529952883,51.236590954855],[4.4322857553331,51.236057528816],[4.4324665414776,51.235296416762],[4.4327679095033,51.234078628712],[4.436063118197,51.231371154144],[4.4407546751814,51.228481674736],[4.44120602428,51.22818010735],[4.4449082376716,51.225601039185],[4.4480856719633,51.22325880169],[4.4488521236098,51.222556237324],[4.4496988898229,51.221661459484],[4.4499856403436,51.221052446033],[4.4499841360901,51.220196300884],[4.4497406856796,51.219578141436],[4.4490960462471,51.218863231728],[4.4482711707646,51.21841754446],[4.4478124066088,51.218446560163],[4.4476047941564,51.218436171014],[4.4473409671726,51.218282241199],[4.4465018827972,51.217536531639],[4.4464444676391,51.217437697284],[4.4462759440588,51.217284112586],[4.4461596772113,51.217080469962],[4.4461987803246,51.216017691801],[4.4460096186879,51.215629069783],[4.4458998017019,51.215172529991],[4.4458619363702,51.214265038019],[4.4457245572314,51.21362587134],[4.4456150799702,51.213369098295],[4.4457077035225,51.213323575876],[4.4459692357575,51.213051666847],[4.4460414843154,51.212946451114],[4.4460555820161,51.212803604147],[4.4459134415878,51.212455676999],[4.4444398889796,51.21121559864],[4.4431105114184,51.209946119322],[4.4412911154577,51.208651620335],[4.4411250282473,51.208450147598],[4.4409633829374,51.208257993778],[4.4408338748643,51.208138270327],[4.4405074092184,51.207196648078],[4.4403139697453,51.206792532104],[4.4392685134801,51.20512551562],[4.4382214909318,51.203699222971],[4.4373568079363,51.202655228227],[4.43611967855,51.201617148595],[4.4356150571515,51.201398473887],[4.4352188950159,51.201111207417],[4.4336272002478,51.199386853112],[4.4316990046185,51.197755508874],[4.4305346060729,51.196568930064],[4.4297055465229,51.195697336797],[4.4279776861848,51.194223737353],[4.4251145478916,51.19278871644],[4.4229996956955,51.19199563967],[4.4224273098666,51.191816134623],[4.4214992681335,51.1916533261],[4.4202183954108,51.19153403692],[4.4190423885719,51.191535797781],[4.4179676825585,51.191669436356],[4.4168022058999,51.191869692949],[4.4155308072131,51.192127056631],[4.4138336135775,51.192278683437],[4.4131887215169,51.192307469942],[4.4131069988229,51.192336040472],[4.4130154137208,51.192460312423],[4.4129437123685,51.192558702488],[4.4127539885049,51.192560973884],[4.4125268950846,51.192552498028],[4.4121726245213,51.192535507749],[4.4117547664856,51.192512832248],[4.4111597627351,51.192470243105],[4.4103694543615,51.192413451835],[4.4102094712823,51.192417017217],[4.4101550224844,51.192474113518],[4.410146021469,51.192565439747],[4.4101879567986,51.192601870419],[4.4102460112475,51.192645311734],[4.410636615664,51.192662294703],[4.4113996782541,51.192719094179],[4.4119719687152,51.192753129021],[4.4126583461522,51.192773005266],[4.41260155662,51.193222450938],[4.4125457884412,51.193314469081],[4.4124822741906,51.19338869291],[4.4124177359844,51.193466425291],[4.4123279455402,51.193485781506],[4.4122098601339,51.193488679528],[4.4120735954988,51.193477314988],[4.4118463780423,51.193446466435],[4.4117545578829,51.19338676476],[4.4116783633304,51.193374723174],[4.4113967765649,51.193380534468],[4.4112605230138,51.19338058436],[4.4110561190163,51.19335497432],[4.4107835662046,51.193306557837],[4.4104110419768,51.193198244981],[4.4100430598058,51.193089930231],[4.4097341107293,51.192967324307],[4.4095477951414,51.192850382265],[4.4093933065071,51.192773381715],[4.4090798973029,51.192739244799],[4.4087892519638,51.192767883779],[4.4084713742432,51.192819362114],[4.4082443393368,51.192879371165],[4.4080763415987,51.192933651214],[4.4078937014555,51.193000005696],[4.4075395933969,51.193177062852],[4.4073681097867,51.193267788657],[4.4071229839703,51.193424832237],[4.4068042336086,51.193668169118],[4.4064955595904,51.193873746621],[4.4062287379716,51.194021578574],[4.4060425733344,51.1940844231],[4.4058382370147,51.194144419299],[4.4056384296733,51.194187290647],[4.4053523287557,51.194233043664],[4.4050026238094,51.194258838092],[4.4047437483963,51.194273187953],[4.4044439789519,51.194267572949],[4.4040760873504,51.194267685651],[4.403744535086,51.194273493925],[4.4035301299881,51.194361834338],[4.4031986844239,51.194542573037],[4.402989799831,51.194599712708],[4.4025999728403,51.194609462046],[4.4020885475982,51.194610172207],[4.4017634581421,51.194565821842],[4.40140866483,51.194491801707],[4.4012274083518,51.194417573726],[4.4010911503319,51.194417611893],[4.4006279735531,51.19455472488],[4.3998923674121,51.194823187368],[4.3932169099339,51.197027966398],[4.3918379736335,51.197508946249],[4.3904103234081,51.197993129819],[4.3905221151741,51.198135430202],[4.3905376394212,51.198267075018],[4.3904196130627,51.198421204647],[4.3905923119739,51.198609525125],[4.3901284358701,51.199133196955],[4.389982786503,51.199051905442],[4.3898021162039,51.198963549869],[4.389738668055,51.199277484483],[4.3898569468633,51.199654170046],[4.3900115978478,51.200099340747],[4.3902286752797,51.200629797241],[4.3902773319835,51.201055961398],[4.3901928517152,51.201718068631],[4.3900961160204,51.202083378338],[4.3899025459966,51.202616131028],[4.3895149061023,51.202623811657],[4.3884251178987,51.202751646755],[4.3866281424585,51.20348522578],[4.3862419333132,51.203754939235],[4.3850817706146,51.203496651029],[4.3827713606488,51.202681361057],[4.3810298543787,51.202182143306],[4.3786827633643,51.201944557526],[4.3771307214505,51.202063596882],[4.3742992133725,51.202591740357],[4.3730499809217,51.202667902226],[4.3726108555936,51.202686945807],[4.3725490606787,51.202731569532],[4.3723988778732,51.202848671271],[4.3719875998739,51.203929179743],[4.370170644135,51.207734339811],[4.3696163810059,51.208577387731],[4.3695282175263,51.208674573555],[4.3656342985698,51.21195435712],[4.3636752689093,51.213314978704],[4.3620899698605,51.21443706027],[4.3616588782739,51.214913630984],[4.3612346173258,51.216036111675],[4.3611436077073,51.21691127921],[4.3611434722878,51.217824502307],[4.3613250768669,51.218947015929],[4.3615636491123,51.219728699372],[4.3618080298616,51.219863652548],[4.3623246824206,51.220069570377],[4.3634759216251,51.220145722594],[4.3658390083714,51.22018384201],[4.3662393796012,51.220425501667],[4.3661722319786,51.221001942045],[4.365459381213,51.227330564055],[4.3657942659482,51.227814390233],[4.3681732082717,51.230192023882],[4.3694689275775,51.231627742777],[4.3709612147244,51.23296969268],[4.3727189922203,51.234225310445],[4.3752648501046,51.235671109447]]]}","gisid":"LEZ_01","naam":"Lage-emissiezone (LEZ)","shape":null,"shape_area":"22810825.358015","shape_len":"20944.458705765"}]}
```

This piece of your GeoJson is valid according to geojsonlint.com, but isn't a Feature or FeatureCollection, so doesn't work with the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer):

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.3752648501046,51.235671109447],[4.3768261156089,51.235987379867],[4.378205111297,51.236258380179],[4.3793189154647,51.236424751374],[4.381175249257,51.236619570007],[4.3821299391582,51.236714586479],[4.3826224317521,51.236738309085],[4.3847741845381,51.236652409815],[4.3870320006657,51.236566455329],[4.3905641334774,51.236418346457],[4.3933355001615,51.236027810783],[4.3953204030054,51.235751501796],[4.3964719325386,51.235580002999],[4.397631024507,51.235398977832],[4.3989492000278,51.235198875137],[4.4004535188848,51.235118174476],[4.4024418721928,51.235102784205],[4.4025175087519,51.235345894895],[4.4032165369956,51.235338394238],[4.403406877327,51.235341114003],[4.4044813217503,51.23533389126],[4.4047722441325,51.235316678533],[4.4050631360141,51.235259511945],[4.4053904063446,51.235219455944],[4.4057540767169,51.235219340598],[4.4060359480456,51.235253495989],[4.4064318055827,51.235325580515],[4.4067051745177,51.236067480356],[4.4067816576535,51.236932157158],[4.408069417218,51.236957496301],[4.4085517807897,51.236992303044],[4.4085551128357,51.237861034679],[4.408897111612,51.237856366303],[4.4092133965522,51.237852607418],[4.4092596122389,51.237690514702],[4.409307498352,51.237005585527],[4.4115683830778,51.23698955552],[4.4146387269243,51.236929323909],[4.4178627148587,51.236828131985],[4.4186098703507,51.236911526049],[4.4188646220169,51.237071229427],[4.4188672599631,51.239491250744],[4.4190314627796,51.239982033231],[4.4194137832192,51.240369984415],[4.4197606223084,51.241327202393],[4.4197599521063,51.244000523224],[4.4205172754282,51.244181323957],[4.4206091889183,51.241231702419],[4.4208346952824,51.240248765404],[4.4239856975874,51.239296052026],[4.4291989404206,51.237378040829],[4.4309529952883,51.236590954855],[4.4322857553331,51.236057528816],[4.4324665414776,51.235296416762],[4.4327679095033,51.234078628712],[4.436063118197,51.231371154144],[4.4407546751814,51.228481674736],[4.44120602428,51.22818010735],[4.4449082376716,51.225601039185],[4.4480856719633,51.22325880169],[4.4488521236098,51.222556237324],[4.4496988898229,51.221661459484],[4.4499856403436,51.221052446033],[4.4499841360901,51.220196300884],[4.4497406856796,51.219578141436],[4.4490960462471,51.218863231728],[4.4482711707646,51.21841754446],[4.4478124066088,51.218446560163],[4.4476047941564,51.218436171014],[4.4473409671726,51.218282241199],[4.4465018827972,51.217536531639],[4.4464444676391,51.217437697284],[4.4462759440588,51.217284112586],[4.4461596772113,51.217080469962],[4.4461987803246,51.216017691801],[4.4460096186879,51.215629069783],[4.4458998017019,51.215172529991],[4.4458619363702,51.214265038019],[4.4457245572314,51.21362587134],[4.4456150799702,51.213369098295],[4.4457077035225,51.213323575876],[4.4459692357575,51.213051666847],[4.4460414843154,51.212946451114],[4.4460555820161,51.212803604147],[4.4459134415878,51.212455676999],[4.4444398889796,51.21121559864],[4.4431105114184,51.209946119322],[4.4412911154577,51.208651620335],[4.4411250282473,51.208450147598],[4.4409633829374,51.208257993778],[4.4408338748643,51.208138270327],[4.4405074092184,51.207196648078],[4.4403139697453,51.206792532104],[4.4392685134801,51.20512551562],[4.4382214909318,51.203699222971],[4.4373568079363,51.202655228227],[4.43611967855,51.201617148595],[4.4356150571515,51.201398473887],[4.4352188950159,51.201111207417],[4.4336272002478,51.199386853112],[4.4316990046185,51.197755508874],[4.4305346060729,51.196568930064],[4.4297055465229,51.195697336797],[4.4279776861848,51.194223737353],[4.4251145478916,51.19278871644],[4.4229996956955,51.19199563967],[4.4224273098666,51.191816134623],[4.4214992681335,51.1916533261],[4.4202183954108,51.19153403692],[4.4190423885719,51.191535797781],[4.4179676825585,51.191669436356],[4.4168022058999,51.191869692949],[4.4155308072131,51.192127056631],[4.4138336135775,51.192278683437],[4.4131887215169,51.192307469942],[4.4131069988229,51.192336040472],[4.4130154137208,51.192460312423],[4.4129437123685,51.192558702488],[4.4127539885049,51.192560973884],[4.4125268950846,51.192552498028],[4.4121726245213,51.192535507749],[4.4117547664856,51.192512832248],[4.4111597627351,51.192470243105],[4.4103694543615,51.192413451835],[4.4102094712823,51.192417017217],[4.4101550224844,51.192474113518],[4.410146021469,51.192565439747],[4.4101879567986,51.192601870419],[4.4102460112475,51.192645311734],[4.410636615664,51.192662294703],[4.4113996782541,51.192719094179],[4.4119719687152,51.192753129021],[4.4126583461522,51.192773005266],[4.41260155662,51.193222450938],[4.4125457884412,51.193314469081],[4.4124822741906,51.19338869291],[4.4124177359844,51.193466425291],[4.4123279455402,51.193485781506],[4.4122098601339,51.193488679528],[4.4120735954988,51.193477314988],[4.4118463780423,51.193446466435],[4.4117545578829,51.19338676476],[4.4116783633304,51.193374723174],[4.4113967765649,51.193380534468],[4.4112605230138,51.19338058436],[4.4110561190163,51.19335497432],[4.4107835662046,51.193306557837],[4.4104110419768,51.193198244981],[4.4100430598058,51.193089930231],[4.4097341107293,51.192967324307],[4.4095477951414,51.192850382265],[4.4093933065071,51.192773381715],[4.4090798973029,51.192739244799],[4.4087892519638,51.192767883779],[4.4084713742432,51.192819362114],[4.4082443393368,51.192879371165],[4.4080763415987,51.192933651214],[4.4078937014555,51.193000005696],[4.4075395933969,51.193177062852],[4.4073681097867,51.193267788657],[4.4071229839703,51.193424832237],[4.4068042336086,51.193668169118],[4.4064955595904,51.193873746621],[4.4062287379716,51.194021578574],[4.4060425733344,51.1940844231],[4.4058382370147,51.194144419299],[4.4056384296733,51.194187290647],[4.4053523287557,51.194233043664],[4.4050026238094,51.194258838092],[4.4047437483963,51.194273187953],[4.4044439789519,51.194267572949],[4.4040760873504,51.194267685651],[4.403744535086,51.194273493925],[4.4035301299881,51.194361834338],[4.4031986844239,51.194542573037],[4.402989799831,51.194599712708],[4.4025999728403,51.194609462046],[4.4020885475982,51.194610172207],[4.4017634581421,51.194565821842],[4.40140866483,51.194491801707],[4.4012274083518,51.194417573726],[4.4010911503319,51.194417611893],[4.4006279735531,51.19455472488],[4.3998923674121,51.194823187368],[4.3932169099339,51.197027966398],[4.3918379736335,51.197508946249],[4.3904103234081,51.197993129819],[4.3905221151741,51.198135430202],[4.3905376394212,51.198267075018],[4.3904196130627,51.198421204647],[4.3905923119739,51.198609525125],[4.3901284358701,51.199133196955],[4.389982786503,51.199051905442],[4.3898021162039,51.198963549869],[4.389738668055,51.199277484483],[4.3898569468633,51.199654170046],[4.3900115978478,51.200099340747],[4.3902286752797,51.200629797241],[4.3902773319835,51.201055961398],[4.3901928517152,51.201718068631],[4.3900961160204,51.202083378338],[4.3899025459966,51.202616131028],[4.3895149061023,51.202623811657],[4.3884251178987,51.202751646755],[4.3866281424585,51.20348522578],[4.3862419333132,51.203754939235],[4.3850817706146,51.203496651029],[4.3827713606488,51.202681361057],[4.3810298543787,51.202182143306],[4.3786827633643,51.201944557526],[4.3771307214505,51.202063596882],[4.3742992133725,51.202591740357],[4.3730499809217,51.202667902226],[4.3726108555936,51.202686945807],[4.3725490606787,51.202731569532],[4.3723988778732,51.202848671271],[4.3719875998739,51.203929179743],[4.370170644135,51.207734339811],[4.3696163810059,51.208577387731],[4.3695282175263,51.208674573555],[4.3656342985698,51.21195435712],[4.3636752689093,51.213314978704],[4.3620899698605,51.21443706027],[4.3616588782739,51.214913630984],[4.3612346173258,51.216036111675],[4.3611436077073,51.21691127921],[4.3611434722878,51.217824502307],[4.3613250768669,51.218947015929],[4.3615636491123,51.219728699372],[4.3618080298616,51.219863652548],[4.3623246824206,51.220069570377],[4.3634759216251,51.220145722594],[4.3658390083714,51.22018384201],[4.3662393796012,51.220425501667],[4.3661722319786,51.221001942045],[4.365459381213,51.227330564055],[4.3657942659482,51.227814390233],[4.3681732082717,51.230192023882],[4.3694689275775,51.231627742777],[4.3709612147244,51.23296969268],[4.3727189922203,51.234225310445],[4.3752648501046,51.235671109447]]]}
```

**UPDATE:**

As you have a valid "geometry" in your JSON, you can read it in (assuming the cross-domain request is allowed) and add the pieces Google's Data Layer is looking for:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LbeL1mv/3/)

Empty object:

```
var polygon = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {}
  }]
};
```

Code to read in the JSON and combine it with the above:

```
$.getJSON("http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v4/gis/lezafbakening.json", function(data) {
    polygon.features[0].geometry = $.parseJSON(data.data[0].geometry);
    map.data.addGeoJson(polygon);
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.87, -156),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // map.data.addGeoJson(polygon);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': "Antwerp"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
  $.getJSON("http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v4/gis/lezafbakening.json", function(data) {
    polygon.features[0].geometry = $.parseJSON(data.data[0].geometry);
    map.data.addGeoJson(polygon);
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var polygon = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {}
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: When I just copy and paste the data it is valid, but when i want to use the link it does not recognize the good data =>  {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [4.3752648501046,51.235671109447],[4.3768261156089,51.235987379867],....,[4.3752648501046,51.235671109447],
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: What does "When I just copy and paste the data" mean?  For google maps DataLayer, the top level object must have a type of FeatureCollection or Feature (as the error message indicates).  If I paste the JSON above ("Your JSON") into the text box on geojsonlint.com, I get an error: `Invalid GeoJSON Line 1: The type property is required and was not found`

Comment: What I mean is: there has to be a way to use the link although there is no  type of FeatureCollection or Feature